# Linear Regression or Spline Fit?

Tags: regression, smoothing, splines

I have data with 2 variables: X - Area Size of a field, Y - Average Production Rate. I need to check the relation between the two. I have plotted the data, and got the following two graphs:

[image]

and

[image]

Now I have a dilemma. Should I fit a linear regression model, or should I take into account all the little fluctuations in the trend, as shows in the smoothed curve. Which model is better, linear regression or spline fit (which I am not too familiar with).  Won't I get overfitting by using the spline model here?

Comment: What questions are you trying to answer? In general these plots are very suboptimal: figures without labelled axes are next to impossible to interpreter.

Comment: I didn't add values to the axis on purpose, I can't publish the data. I am trying to test if there is a relation (clearly there is), and to make predictions, if possible. Regression analysis. I just noticed the fluctuations.

Comment: The issue of  overfitting requires knowledge of sample size. There may be other alternative to consider such as nonlinear regression.  You need to provide more details.

Comment: The sample size is N=70. The mean of X is 92.1 with SD of 128, the mean of Y is 318,521 with SD of 475,588. The range of X is 552. If I fit a linear regression, I get an R squared of 0.8.

Comment: What other information do you require in order to determine the better approach here?

Comment: I have transformed Y to it's LOG value (LN), and got an interesting discovery. First of all, now Y is normally distributed (approximately) and secondly, now the relation of LOG(Y) and X is not linear anymore.

Comment: If you cannot publish our data, you should publish plots of them either (annotated or not). Having said that, you do say that: "*X - Area Size of a field, Y - Average Production Rate*" in your first sentence already so we infer that much; I mostly ask for units and the overall modelling task. In any case, talk about the problem you try to solve. Generally speaking a spline seems overly flexible for an "area-to-production" relation but currently there is not enough information to do an informed suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Polynomials are notoriously bad at extrapolating trends. They are mathematically bound to go to $\pm \infty$ whereas our intuition of trends does not. This should be a cautionary tale for anyone considering splines for inference or prediction.  Looking at your graphic, I am certain that is displaying overfitting, which applies to your question whether it is for inferential or predictive statistics.

You can penalize your splines, like with a LOESS smoother, if your desire is to generate a descriptive non-parametric summary of a possibly non-linear trend.

In your comments you note you transform $Y$ to log and the trend is non-linear. It seems to me your visual inspection of these data is heavily weighted by the high influence/leverage points in the tails. It seems less than 5% of the data lie in the right 2/3rds of the graphic. I would suggest graphing these data with a log transform applied to the $X$ axis. If you would like to find a single polynomial function which relates $X$ to $Y$ in this graphic, consider the use of fractional polynomials, rather than fitting scads of models higgledy piggledy.

Comment: May I directly ask: What is the advantage of polynomials then? I assume extrapolating is the most popular case? Despite of that: Isn't it, that polynomials display the underlying/physical behaviour which is most the case?

Comment: @Ben in inferential statistics and in prediction, we use the polynomials to *interpolate* values. Forecasting differs from prediction in that the objective of the model is predicting means and uncertainty for values that lie beyond the range of observed values.